# Snowpack config only works for dev or build, but not both

Tags: javascript, es6-modules, snowpack

I have a snowpack project with the following folder structure:

- build : contains the built project
- src : contains the source files
- node_modules
- package.json
- snowpack.config.js

I set the following config:

```
// Snowpack Configuration File
module.exports = {
    mount: {
        "src": "/",
    }
};
```

This works when I use `snowpack build`: the files from `src` are neatly placed in the build folder and I can access it using the url `http://localhost/myproject/build/index.html` on my computer.

Problem: when I use `snowpack dev`, for some reason snowpack tries to find the `build` folder inside the `src` folder ?!?

> 404 ERROR /Users/oldhank/Sites/basics-snowpack/src/build/_snowpack/pkg/@tensorflow/tfjs

If I remove the `config` file the `dev` works too, but then I need to have all my project files in the root directory, which looks ugly?

How can I get both the `dev` and `build` commands working with a `src` and `build` folder?

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps anyone trying to dev + build + deploy (gh-pages) Snowpack apps:
https://github.com/jgrizou/snowpack-boilerplate

Above link contains a boilerplate for Snowpack app.